# Change custom element Index title via getTableAttributeHtml?

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype, index

I want to change the title in the index of an custom element.

```
public function getTableAttributeHtml(BaseElementModel $element, $attribute)
{
    switch ($attribute)
    {
        case 'title' :
        {
            return $element->attribute . 'blabla';
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

But whatever I try, the title field didn't change. Other fields are no problem.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the answer to this question.

From [BaseElementType defineAvailableTableAttributes() docs](https://craftcms.com/classreference/elementtypes/BaseElementType#defineAvailableTableAttributes-detail),

> The *first* item that this array returns will just identify the database
>   column name, and the table column’s header, but will not have any
>   effect on what shows up in the table’s body. That’s because the first
>   column is reserved for displaying whatever your element model’s
>   *__toString()* method returns (the string representation of the element).

So all you need to do is add a *__toString()* method in your model and return the string representation of your element:

For example:

```
public function __toString()
{
   return $this->id;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could hide the default title column and add your own:

```
public function modifyEntryTableAttributes(&$attributes, $source)
{
    if ($source == 'section:2')
    {
        $attributes = array();
        $attributes['myOwnTitle'] = Craft::t('Title');
        $attributes['uri'] = Craft::t('URI');
        $attributes['postDate'] = Craft::t('Post Date');
        $attributes['expiryDate'] = Craft::t('Expiry Date');
    }
}

public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)
{
    switch ($attribute)
    {
        case 'myOwnTitle':
        {
            return 'blabla';
        }

        ...
    }
}
```